# Can I change the source map URL output

Tags: sass

I use this command in the terminal to watch a scss folder.

`sass --watch templates/default_site/stylesheet.group/scss:templates/default_site/stylesheet.group/ --style compressed`

It outputs a css file into the directory above with the below comment at the bottom of the .css file.

`/*# sourceMappingURL=build.css.map */`

This throws an error in the console when looking on the website saying source map can not be found. I assume it's because there is no propper path to the file.

How do I amend my terminal command to output the correct path into the outputted css file?

file structure:

```
root
    templates 
        default_site
            stylesheet.group
                build.css
                build.css.map
                scss
                    build.scss
```

Browser Error

```
Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://www.domain.co.uk/?css=stylesheet/build.v.1620224463
Source Map URL: build.css.map
```

Comment: could you add your public file structure?

Comment: @Joseph should be in there now,

Comment: your build path is correct, could you add your browser error?